# How to get the previous and next related post in django?

Tags: django

**views.py**

```
def post_details(request,pk):
    post = Post.objects.get(id=pk)
    # next_post = Post.objects.filter(id=pk)
    context={'post':post,'next':next_post}
    return render(request, 'blog/post_detail.html', context)
```

**blog-detail**

```
<div class="s-content__pagenav group">
    <div class="prev-nav">
        <a href="#" rel="prev">
            <span>Previous</span>
            Tips on Minimalist Design 
        </a>
    </div>
    
     <div class="next-nav">
         <a href="#" rel="next">
             <span>Next</span>
            Less Is More 
         </a>
     </div>
</div>
```

**models**

```
# this is my model
class User(AbstractUser):
    # pass
    name = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    bio = models.TextField(null=True)
    email = models.EmailField(unique=True, null=True)
    avatar = models.ImageField( null=True, upload_to='blog_media', default="images/avatar.svg")
    facebook = models.URLField(blank=True, null=True)
    twitter = models.URLField(blank=True, null=True)
    dribbble = models.URLField(blank=True, null=True)
    instagram = models.URLField(blank=True, null=True)

class Category(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=20)
    
    class Meta:
        verbose_name = 'Category'
        verbose_name_plural = 'Categories'

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name

class Post(models.Model):
    author = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    category = models.ManyToManyField(Category)
    title = models.CharField(max_length=200, blank=False);
    description = models.TextField(null=True,blank=True)
    image = models.ImageField(upload_to='blog_media') 
    url = models.URLField(null=True, blank=True)
    body = HTMLField()
    created = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)
    updated = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.title
```

Comment: Related *how*? Please share your `Post` model.

Comment: i have done it sir

Comment: You still don't answer what you mean by "_previous and next related post_". How are the posts _related_? Do you mean to get the previous / next posts by their created timestamp or similar?

Comment: get by similar sir

Comment: @Udonwa: and when are two posts "similar"?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on your comments, I'm assuming that you would like to get two related posts that have the same `category` as the current post.

If I'm correct, then one method you could use is to `filter` the `queryset` for the same `category` belonging to the current post then you could choose the next and previous posts of the current post from the retrieved `queryset`. For example:

```
def post_details(request, pk):
     current_post = Post.objects.get(pk=pk) # retrieving the current post...
   
     # filtering for related posts only by using the category of the current post
     # using -> category_in=post.category.all() since it's a ManyToMany field
     related_posts = Post.objects.filter(category_in=current_post.category.all())

     # next -> get posts with id greater than the current post id, then get the first instance 'next post'
     # previous -> get posts with id less than the current post id, then get the first instance 'previous post'
     context = {
          'post': current_post,
          'next': related_posts.filter(id__gt=current_post.id).order_by('id').first(), 
          'previous': related_posts.filter(id__lt=current_post.id).order_by('-id').first()
     }

     return render(request, 'blog/post_detail.html', context)
```

Ideally, that should work.

A quick recommendation here as well... Instead of using `Post.objects.get(pk=pk)`, I'd suggest using `get_object_or_404()` as this will handle any potential error that `Post.objects.get(pk=pk)` will throw. So a small update...

```
from django.shortcuts import get_object_or_404

def post_details(request, pk):
     current_post = get_object_or_404(Post, pk=pk) # retrieving the current post...

     # the rest of the code follows...
```

Comment: No problem at all  :-)